# Como fazer uma expressão regular para remover somente o hífen sem remover a seta com hífen

Tags: php, javascript, regex, expressões

Tenho a seguinte expressão:

> 00000-001->22222-222

Gostaria que ela ficasse assim:

> 00000001->22222222

Eu tentei de várias formas [neste site](http://regexr.com/3d12q), mas não estou conseguindo.

Comment: PHP ou JavaScript? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode usar [negative lookahead "(?!)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749437/regular-expression-negative-lookahead), negar um padrão que vem a frente de outro padrão. Exemplo em php:

```
preg_replace('/-(?!>)/', '', '00000-001->22222-222');
```

Ou em javascript:

```js
var result = '00000-001->22222-222'.replace(/-(?!>)/g, '');
document.write(result);
```

O pattern `/-(?!>)/` quer dizer "`-` que não sejam diretamente seguidos por `>`" e vai te devolver `"00000001->22222222"`.

Comment: Reparei agora que a pergunta tem tag PHP e JavaScript (!)... `+1` pela resposta com PHP :P

Comment: Perfeito cara, valeu!

Answer (score 4):

Podes fazer assim:

```
var str = '00000-001->22222-222';
var limpa = str.replace(/\-/g, function(match, pos) {
    return str.slice(pos + 1, pos + 2).match(/\d/) ? '' : '-';
});
console.log(limpa); // dá 00000001->22222222
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0jj507w1/1

ou como o BrunoRB [sugeriu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/118479/como-fazer-uma-express%C3%A3o-regular-para-remover-somente-o-h%C3%ADfen-sem-remover-a-seta#comment247264_118482):

```
var str = '00000-001->22222-222';
var limpa = str.replace(/\-([^>])/g, '$1');
console.log(limpa); // dá 00000001->22222222
```

#### jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0jj507w1/2

Comment: Sergio está errado porque sua regex vai considerar o elemento que vem a frente de `-` como parte da regex e acabar removendo um "0" da string, note como a entrada tem 7 zeros e a saída tem 6. Você pode arrumar ela usando group capture, algo como `.replace(/\-([^>])/g, '$1');`

Comment: @BrunoRB tens razão, obrigado. Corrigi.